# Обновить данные в GridView

Tags: c#, gridview

Как обновить данные в `GridView`, если он привязан через `DataSource`

Answer (score 1):

`GridView.DataBind()`?

Comment: В смысле обновить данные в соответствии с их редактированием в GridView

Comment: @Verling, сделайте апдейт данных в хэндлерах событий обновлений GridView. Например <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx">вот так</a>